# How to change step count inside the loop using php

Tags: php

How would i change the step (value) text for each loop iteration? I know i am not doing it right, just not sure how this would work.

```
<?php

$count = 10;
$step_count = 1;    

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
  $result = "Step 1" . $step_count;
  $step_count + 1;

  echo '<br>';
  echo $result;
}
?>
```

**Output**

Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1
Step 1

**Output i want to show is**

Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
Step 5
Step 6
Step 7
Step 8
Step 9
Step 10

Comment: Did you try $step_count = $step_count + 1; ?

Comment: `$step_count += 1`, `$step_count++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$count = 10;
$step_count = 1;

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $result = "Step" . " " . $step_count;
    $step_count = $step_count + 1;

    echo '<br>';
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = 1;
$end = 10;
$step = 1;

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $step) {
  echo "<br>Step $i";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write `$step_count += 1` instead `$step_count + 1`;